# Solve for logarithmic function: $\dfrac{\log(1+0.35\alpha)}{\log(1+\alpha)}=0.8\;$

Tags: logarithms, problem-solving

I am having a logarithmic function of the form:

$\dfrac{\log(1+0.35\alpha)}{\log(1+\alpha)}=0.8\;.$

I want to find out the value of alpha that solves this equation. For that I am taking log term on the denominator to the other side.

$\log(1+0.35\alpha)=0.8\log(1+\alpha)\;.$

Since base of logarithm is 10,the equation becomes

$1+0.35\alpha=(1+\alpha)^{0.8}\;.$

But since one term is having power $0.8$, how to solve this. Is there any alternative method for solving this type of logarithmic equations.

Comment: Please use Latex in this website, link for basic tutorial: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: You could rewrite it as finding the roots of $(1+0.35x)^5-(1+x)^4$. By inspection, one root is $x=0$, so you could divide by $x$ to get a quartic polynomial, which does have closed form roots (but they would have a very messy exact formula).

Comment: Deepa, you can see the solutions [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%281%2B7x%2F20%29%5E5%3D%281%2Bx%29%5E4). If you want to see the exact forms of them, you have to click on “Exact forms” button. Of course the solution $\alpha\approx-1.42263376234029$ cannot be accepted because for $\alpha\leqslant-1$ the logarithms are not defined. Consequently, the only real solutions of your logarithmic equation are : $\alpha=0$ and $\alpha\approx179.918540040531$.

Comment: The logarithms could be in any base. Fun the fun, I made may calculations with my phone.

Comment: If $\alpha+1=x$, then you have a general trinomial, with [this solution](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/418392/series-solution-for-general-trinomial)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that graphing, you noticed that the solution is a large number.

To get an *estimate*, "ignore" the $1$'s

$$\log \left(0+\frac{ 7}{20}a\right)=\frac 4 5 \log \left(0+a\right)\implies \frac{7 }{20}a=a^{\frac 4 5 }\implies a_0=\frac{3200000}{16807}$$
Now, consider that you look for the zero of function
$$f(a)=\log \left(1+\frac{7 }{20}a\right)-\frac 4 5 \log \left(1+a\right)$$ and compute the first iteration of Newton method using the previous $a_0$.

It gives
$$a_1=a_0-\frac{\log \left(1+\frac{7 }{20}a_0\right)-\frac 4 5 \log \left(1+a\right) } {\frac{7 a_0-45}{5 (a_0+1) (7 a_0+20)}}$$ that is to say
$$a_1=\frac{3200000}{16807}-\frac{10448253472140 }{10393297537}\left(\log
   \left(\frac{162401}{2401}\right)-\frac{4}{5} \log
   \left(\frac{3216807}{16807}\right)\right)$$

Converted to decimals, $a_0=190.397$, $a_1=179.636$ while the "exact" solution is $179.919$

Comment: What does finding zero of the function mean in the above equation

Comment: @Deepa. Cross multiply your expression and subtract the rhs from the lhs to get the function you want the zero of which